# Wordpress: Pulling alt text from media item

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

I'm working on designing an image blog but am running into a few issues. I was able to pull the "caption" area of the media item for the lightbox, but I'm unable to pull the "alt" area or the "description" area. Any ideas?

```
<?php if($attachment->post_excerpt): ?>alt="<?php echo $attachment->post_excerpt; ?>"<?php endif; ?>
```

(That is what I use to pull from the media items caption area)

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full'); ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" class="hover-gradient" title="untitled"><p style="display:none;"><?php if($attachment->post_excerpt): ?><?php echo $attachment->post_excerpt; ?><?php endif; ?></p><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>" alt="gallery-blog" /></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

(This is the extended code for the homepage thumbs)

I'm basically looking for something to replace the alt="gallery-blog" area so that it will display the media items alt text from the media page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get the media title,caption and description as like below

```
$alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$image_title = $attachment->post_title;
$caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
$description = $image->post_content;
```

Answer (score 2):

the `wp_get_attachment_image();` function echos out all the information regarding the image including the `alt`, `src`, `width`, `height` and `class`

[Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)